# Cauchy-Schwarz for more than two vectors?

Tags: inequality

Given three or more vectors in an inner product space, $x,y,z, \ldots$, I am wondering whether there exist generalisations to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{equation}
\left| \langle x,y \rangle \right|^2 \leq  \langle x,x \rangle \cdot \langle y,y \rangle.
\end{equation}

I understand that one can construct such inequalities following from the positive semi-definiteness of the Gram matrix but I would like to know if there exist other types?

If so, please provide some references.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Gram matrix generalization is pretty elegant IMO.  Is there something specific you don't like about it?

Comment: I do not dislike the Gram matrix version. However, I was wondering if there are inequalities that look simpler, even if this is at the expense of being the most general/precise. E.g., for three vectors the inequality following from the Gram matrix is quite long; one (quite trivial) inequality for three would be the one following from combining the Cauch-Schwartz for each pair. Are there any other such inequalities for three vectors or more that are known?

Comment: Moreover, I am wondering whether there are inequalities that one can write for the sum of the squares of norms:  $\langle x,x \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle \ldots$ bounded by some combination of all the inner products between them?